# sqlite repeats primary key autoincrement value after rollback

Tags: sqlite

I expect that used and rollback(ed) PK values will be discarded by sqlite, but do not occur that way. here is the test:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO _UIDlgt (id, TS) VALUES (null, '1421248181');
select max(id) from _UIDlgt;         -- shows  6  ok, there were previous records
ROLLBACK;
select max(id) from _UIDlgt;         -- shows  5  ok, was previous max value
INSERT INTO _UIDlgt (id, TS) VALUES (null, '1421248181');
select max(id) from _UIDlgt;         -- shows  6  I expect 7 !!!!
```

This is the table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE _UIDlgt (
   id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
   TS              INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Manual [says](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) that failed inserts skips PK values attempted to use, but noting about rollbacks.
The question is: **Is there some setup to manage this behavior?** or a trick?

Ms Sql Server works the way I expect. Sqlite version is 3.7.7.1 under PHP 5.4.11

Comment: Rollback drops all pending write operations, and autoincrement is a write operation into special `sqlite_sequence` table. Hence, its value changes applies only on commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some subtle language in the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). (Emphasis added.)

> In other words, the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse
>   of ROWIDs **from previously deleted rows**.

This is a little different from a client/server SQL dbms, which has to deal with concurrent writes. SQLite requires an [exclusive lock for writes](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

> With AUTOINCREMENT, rows with automatically selected ROWIDs are
>   guaranteed to have ROWIDs that have never been **used** before by the same
>   table in the same database.

This implies that the guarantee has to do with committed rows. It implies that id numbers for uncommitted rows aren't "used before" (in this sense) in the table.

> However, if an insert fails due to (for example) a uniqueness
>   constraint, the ROWID of the failed insertion attempt **might** not be
>   reused on subsequent inserts, resulting in gaps in the ROWID sequence.

Leaves open the possibility of reuse.

Comment: I interpret the manual in the same way you tell here. so the short answer is "no way"...